# How to parse GraphQL response in apex class?

Tags: graphql

I am wondering if there are any options to directly parse response in GraphQL format just similar to parsing JSON in apex class? Does Salesforce APIs support parsing GraphQL response from an external system?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no native system library or method to utilize GraphQL. However, you can grab an installable code base from the [AppExchange](https://appexchange.salesforce.com/appxSearchKeywordResults?keywords=GraphQL&searchType=simpleSearch).